# How to clear the fill of a rectangle in C#?

Tags: c#, graphics, drawing, gdi

How can I clear the fill of a rectangle? I only want to keep the border.

```
g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Transparent, x, y, w, h);
```

Didn't work, neither did aRGB with alpha, I want to delete the fill so there's only the border left.

Comment: So what color do you want it to be?

Comment: If you've filled it with say red, and now you want to "unfill" it, as well as not filling it or filling it transparent, you need to force a repaint of whatever was behind it which as been thoroughly obscured with aforementioned red...

Comment: None. The rectangles should be overlapping, I have white filled rectangles, but I want to make them transparent after they're finished drawing. It's actually a selection tool I'm working on.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson How can I save the graphic state? It doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Falko. Depends on who's doing what to whom and when. One way it to paint the "parent" control to a bitmap. Draw that when not selecting, when selecting draw it followed by the selection rectangle. If you look inside the eventargs of paint, it gives you the rectangle windows thinks it needs to redraw so you can hack away a flicker and such. Personally I'd make the selection rectangle an other control though, simplifies things.

Answer (score 5):

So what you want is

```
g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black,x,y,w,h);
```

I think

EDIT: due to a change in the OP requirements this is not exactly the answer he wants, though it is not incorrect, therefore I choose to leave it here, for now.

Answer (score 3):

you must set new clip for your graphics after set clip clear it, then restore clip to normal.

```
g.SetClip(new Rectangle(x,y,w,h), CombineMode.Replace);
g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so you are after a selection tool, you might have wanted to tell us that in the first place.

Create a new windows form application.

in the form events  use mousedown, mouseup and mousemove

```
public Point MouseXY = new Point(0, 0);

private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MouseXY = e.Location;
    }

    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            int width = e.Location.X - MouseXY.X;
            int height = e.Location.Y-MouseXY.Y;
            this.Refresh();
            CreateGraphics().DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, new Rectangle(MouseXY, new Size(width,height)));

        }
    }

    private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Refresh();
    }
```

This code is not perfect and I don't pretend it is.  What this will do is draw a blue rectangle that starts where you click and follows your mouse.  It does not draw a negative rectangle, you would have to determine whether your mouse is currently to the left or up from your starting point then draw the rectangle accordingly, but I think you can figure that out on your own.  as well the rectangle is not persistent, though I do not believe you would want it to be.

Comment: Really nice, but when the mouse is up it should keep the rectangle to it's definitive position.

Comment: simply remove the Mouseup event then.  Though you would want to toss the rectangle at that point into a variable so you can keep it.  Also as I said the drawing is not persistant, meaning that if you minimize the form or cover it with another window, it will not redraw the rectangle.  If you wish for that functionality you have to go into the Form.OnPaint method, which is not that hard, but I would need more information on exactly what you need to help out more.